# Followed instructions on php.net and still cannot get mysqli extension to work

Tags: php, dll, mysqli

I uncommented this line in the php.ini file: extension=php_mysqli.dll
and my extension is "extension_dir = "ext"".

The php_mysqli.dll does exist in the ext folder.

I am using php 5.5+ so I should not have to manually set the path for libmysql.dll.

Running mysqli_connect yields a fatal error.

I do not understand why this does not work. When I did this with my php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll file, I was able to connect to sql server immediately. I do not see anything I missed in these installation instructions:

http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Where do I go from here?

---

Windows 7
apache 2.4 
php 5.5.9
No instance of mysql in this machine.

Comment: what does `phpinfo()` say ?

Comment: sqlsrv support is enabled but I cannot find anything with regards to mysqli or mysql. The only thing related to mysql I see is the  mysqlnd table that is displayed from the output of phpinfor().